# Spring dynamic Qualifier

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

I have an interface Shape

```
public interface Shape {
    String draw();
}
```

And two implementations for the above Shape interface

```
@Component("triangle")
public class Triangle implements Shape {
    public String draw() {
        return "drawing Triangle";
    }
}
```

and

```
@Component("circle")
public class Circle implements Shape {
    public String draw() {
        return "Drawing Circle";
    }
}
```

In my client code if I have to decide which Shape class to use at run time based on Qualifier

```
 @Autowired
    private Shape shape;
@GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    @Path("/shape")
    public String getShape(@PathParam("type")
    String type) {
        String a = shape.draw();
        return a;
    }
```

How to do it?
I want to pass "type" which I get as a pathparam to decide which Shape object to be injected at run time. Please help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: What you are trying to do is not autowiring by qualifier but autowiring by bean name. Qualifiers are specified using the special @Qualifier annotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could figure out one way of getting around this by injecting ApplicationContext in the client code.

```
 @Autowired
 private ApplicationContext appContext;
```

And looking up for the bean with the help of getBean method:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
@Path("/shape/{type}")
public String getShape(@PathParam("type")
String type) {
    Shape shape = appContext.getBean(type, Shape.class);
    return shape.draw();
}
```

I hope this would help someone :)

Comment: I think you can also use BeanFactory for this